# Installing Windows 10 iot on Raspberry Pi from Mac

Tags: macos, sd-card, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

I'm a Mac user, and I recently started programming GUI's in C#. I don't find the Storyboard in Xamarin Studio, respectively in Xcode very convenient. So I'm trying to install Windows 10 Iot on my Raspberry Pi 3 to work with Visual Studio. After a lot of searching I still can't find a way to burn Windows (.iso ).img file on the SD card from my Mac. I tried using the virtual machine with Windows Guest OS, since Microsoft has a special program to do this on Windows, but it doesn't detect the SD card.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried using NOOBS? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Docs/GetStarted/noobs/GetStartedStep1.htm

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2015/06/05/copy-iso-to-usb-drive-mac-os-x-command/

Comment: Thank you @LynnCrumbling it worked with Noobs ^_^" . I still have problems installing sofware on it because I don't have the Dashboard ..

Answer (score 0):

Within Parallels Desktop with your Windows 10 VM booted, share the SD card from your MacOS to your Windows VM PC.

[Share Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Auxyz.png)

Once you have done this you will be able to see the SD card within Windows IoT.

[IoT Format SD Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcxTU.png)